# Calls for files are made in the wrong file path

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I am trying to build an Angular App and I have the following situation in ASP.NET MVC.
I have created an App folder in the root directory of the project that contains the following:

- styles folder
- scripts folder
- images folder
- index.html file

Then instead of returning a View in my HomeController Index Action I returned the following:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
      return File(Server.MapPath("/App/index.html"), "text/html");
 }
```

the index.html has a the following style added:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
```

When I run the app the index.html gets retrieved but I get an error inside of retrieving the style file:

```
http://localhost:57826/styles/main.css
```

For some reason instead of it looking in the the following path  `http://localhost:57826/App/styles/main.css` it looks in the path mentioned above.

I then tryed to intercept the calls and get the files from the correct path by creating a custom router like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Style",
           url: "styles/{*path}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Www", action = "Style" }
       );

public class WwwController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Style(string path)
    {
        byte[] content = this.GetContent(this.CorrectPath(path, "css"));
        var result = new FileContentResult(content, this.GetContentTypeFor(path));
        return result;
    }

    private string CorrectPath(string path, string folder)
    {
        return Server.MapPath("/App/" + folder + "/" + path);
    }

    private byte[] GetContent(string path)
    {
        byte[] readAllBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        return readAllBytes;
    }

    private string GetContentTypeFor(string path)
    {
        return System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Path.GetFileName(path));
    }
}
```

But my solution does not seem to work.The Style action is not called.Can anyone tell me how can I solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Why are you breaking the MVC model by not allowing your view to do the presentation work?  Simply do this:

```
 public ActionResult Index() {
   return View();
 }
```

Then put whatever content you need into Views/Home/Index.cshtml:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
@* Add link tags, javascript, etc. *@
```

Or just use a vanilla ASP.NET site.

Comment: The same problem persist event view using and MVC file...Anyway this will be an Angular app and I only need the starter HTML file....I still need and ASP.NET MVC app because I will be creating ASP.NET Web.API services